# Capital letter in citation but not in reference list

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm currently writing my PhD thesis and I would like to include a citation to a paper by Y. Saad and H.A. van der Vorst. I use the natbib package (with JabRef) and in the 'author' field I have:

**Saad, Y. and van der Vorst, H.A.**

This gives the correct (with a small 'v' for 'van') output in my reference list:

**Y. Saad and H.A. van der Vorst. Iterative solution of ...**

However, when I cite the paper in the text I get:

**[Saad and van der Vorst, 2000]**

which is wrong, because now the 'van' should be 'Van'. Is there a way to do this, while still having 'van' in the reference list?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Is there any source for the reason of having a capital V in the citation?

Comment: Yes, because that's how Dutch names are written. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_(Dutch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be automated with `biblatex`; with `natbib` you can do something like this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{saad-vandervorst,
  author={Saad, Y. and {\Vv{van}} der Vorst, H. A.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2000,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newif\ifcitation
\citationtrue
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Vv}[1]{\ifcitation Van\else van\fi}

\begin{document}

\citep{saad-vandervorst}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\citationfalse
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, that works perfectly. Thank you very much!